# PhpUnit Test - Asserting variables and twig template content

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, swiftmailer

I've defined a simple email controller based on this tutorial:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email.html

So the php file code is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Tests\Controller;


class SendEmailController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($originlEmail, $destinationEmail1, $destinationEmail2, $name, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Email Title'))
            ->setFrom($originlEmail)
            ->setTo($destinationEmail1, $destinationEmail2)
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'emails/send-email.html.twig',
                    array('name' => $name)
                ),
                'text/html'
            );

        $mailer->send($message);

        return $this->render(...);
    }
}
```

And the .twig template code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h3>This is an email!</h3>
    <p>Hi {{ name }}, this is an email! </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, following this tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email/testing.html I've created a PhpUnit testing class:

```
<?php

namespace tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Controller\SendMyEmailController;

class SendCustomerEmailControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMailIsSentAndContentIsCorrect()
    {
        $client = static:: createClient();

        $client->enableProfiler();

        $crawler = $client->request('POST', 'path/to/above/action');

        $mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');

        $this->assertSame(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

        $collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
        $message = $collectedMessages[0];

        $this->assertInstanceOf('Swift_Message', $message);
        $this->assertSame('My Email Title', $message->getSubject());
        $this->assertSame($originEmail, key($message->getFrom()));
        $this->assertSame($destinationEmail1, $destinationEmail2, key($message->getTo()));
        ##Asserting template content???
        $this->assertSame(?????, $message->getBody()
        );
    }
}
```

Then, the problems I have are:

1. Where and how should I define (in the test) **variables** like $originEmail, given the fact that in the "assertSame..." line, I get the error "Undefined variable $originEmail".
2. Is correct the syntax (considering they are **more than one variable**) of the line  `$this->assertSame($destinationEmail1, $destinationEmail2, key($message->getTo()));` ?
3. How can I **assert the body** content, if instead of a defined text in the .php controller, it is showed in the **.twig template** (in addition, by using a variable like {{ name }}?

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1)

How I would go about this depends on how this information is passed into the action. If it's not part of the request, I would just assert against the expected value by doing something like:

```
$this->assertSame('expected@email.com', $message->getFrom());
```

If it's part of the route I would assign a local variable in the test and then pass it into the route, maybe like this:

```
$originalEmail = 'expected@email.com';
$path = sprintf('/path/to/action/%s', $originalEmail);
$client->request('POST', $path);
...
$this->assertSame($originalEmail, $message->getFrom());
```

If it's part of the POST-data:

```
$data = [
    'originalEmail' => 'expected@email.com',
];
$client->request('POST', '/path/to/action', $data);
...
$this->assertSame($data['originalEmail'], $message->getFrom());
```

Regarding 2)

This will not work as intended, but you can do something like this (if the email is a value in the array):

```
$this->assertContains($destinationEmail1, $message->getTo());
```

Or like this if it's a key (like in your example):

```
$this->assertArrayHasKey($destinationEmail1, $message->getTo());
```

Regarding 3)

If you want to compare that the body matches an example you might have to store a reference output in a file and then compare the contents:

```
$this->assertSame(
    file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/emails/reference_output.html'),
    $message->getBody()
);
```

In that case you have to be careful your email body contains the same name as your reference output.

Alternatively you can also use the [crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#the-crawler) to look only for some html elements and their content, e.g. check if the header `<h3>This is an email!</h3>` is in there:

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/path/to/action');

$this->assertSame(
    'This is an email!',
    $crawler->filter('h3')->first()->text()
);
// alternative:
$this->assertGreaterThan(
    0,
    $crawler->filter('h3:contains("This is an email!")')->count()
);
```

Comment: As a follow up: Checking for the exact email content is probably not a good idea. The content of the email might change and then your test breaks even though the tested behavior, did not actually break. You probably only want to check for the parts of the template that make it possible to identify if the right template was rendered, to make the test less brittle (i.e. only break when behavior was changed).

Comment: Excuse me, but I didn´t understand the possibilities regarding 1) (and 2)). My goal is to pass to the php function an email value which can change (for example, by getting that email address from a form). That's why I make reference to a variable instead of a fix email value. In addition, the two asserts regarding 2) still get the "undefined variable" error.

Comment: If you pass in the data via [a form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#forms) you can use a GET-request to "display" the form and then select the submit button and use this to submit the form data. As soon as I have time I will add it to my answer. The link I provided should already give you a good starting point to try things out.